# Multiple textbox value to one cell

Tags: vba, textbox, cell, frame, userform

I have a userform, within the userform there is a frame with 4 textbox, how would I pass the values of those 4 textbox into one cell? separated by comma or space.

I tried doing the following within my submit button.

```
Dim t As MSForms.Control

For Each t In Me.Frame1.Controls
    If TypeOf t Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        If IsEmpty(stCode1Box) Then
        Exit For
        End If

        If stCode1Box Is Nothing Then
           'Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(stCode1Box) Then
           Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value
        ElseIf stCode2Box Is Nothing Then
           'Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value & ", " & stCode2Box.Value
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(stCode2Box) Then
           Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value & ", " & stCode2Box.Value
        ElseIf stCode3Box Is Nothing Then
           'Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value & ", " & stCode2Box.Value & ", " & stCode3Box.Value
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(stCode3Box) Then
           Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value & ", " & stCode2Box.Value & ", " & stCode3Box.Value
        ElseIf stCode4Box Is Nothing Then
           'Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value & ", " & stCode2Box.Value & ", " & stCode3Box.Value & ", " & stCode4Box.Value
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(stCode4Box) Then
           Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = stCode1Box.Value & ", " & stCode2Box.Value & ", " & stCode3Box.Value & ", " & stCode4Box.Value

        End If
    End If
Next t
```

The result would pop up on that cell, and if more than one textbox had value, this would be separated by a ", " Comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply

```
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value & "," & stCode1Box.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Dim t As MSForms.Control, v
v = ""
For Each t In Me.Frame1.Controls
    If TypeOf t Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        v = v & iif(v <> "", "," , "") & Trim(t.Value)
    End If
Next t
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = v
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop your controls like you already have but rather than having a series of if...elseif statements you could check if the `texbox.value` is not `""`, add the value to an array, then join the array separated by whatever you like.

See my example below which writes your values into cell `C5` on `Sheet1`, assuming your `userform` has a `commandbutton` named cmdSubmit (this will work for any number of `textboxes`):

### Example

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim c As Control
    Dim myCount As Long

    '0 based array starting with a single element
    ReDim temp(0 To 0)
    myCount = 0

    'Check each control for a textbox
    For Each c In Me.Frame1.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            'if there is a value in the texbox then assign it to an array
            If c.Value <> "" Then
                temp(myCount) = c.Value
                myCount = myCount + 1
                'set upperbound of the array +1 when a new value is found
                ReDim Preserve temp(0 To UBound(temp) + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    myCount = 0

    'Remove the last array element as it must be blank
    ReDim Preserve temp(0 To UBound(temp) - 1)

    'Create a string of each value joined with a comma and space
    Dim myString As String
    myString = Join(temp, ", ")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Value = myString

End Sub
```

### References

1. [Array Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function)
2. [Join Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)

Comment: It was recently pointed out to me so I should mention, it would be more efficient to set the upper bound of the array to its largest potential e.g. `ReDim temp (0 to Me.Frame1.Controls.Count`, then run the loop and fill the array. Instead of setting `myCount = 0` after the loop, leave it with its value and only once `ReDim Preserve temp (0 to myCount - 1)`. This removes any empty array elements and leave you with an array full of values and would return the same result as above.